# Schedule job to start at beginning of each hour

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I want some job to be run at start of every hour, e.g at 4'O clock, 5'O clock and so on...

I am trying to use job scheduler, but the problem is the scheduling happens every hour after initial start up e.g if application is started at 4:20, the next run will be 5:20, 6:20 and so on.. I am unable to make it schedule for beginning of each hour (5:00, 6:00) etc..

```
sched = BlockingScheduler() 
sched.add_job(log_setup, 'interval', hours=1)
sched.start()
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is to use the 'cron' scheduler instead of the 'interval' scheduler. So your code would look something like this:

```
  sched.add_job(log_setup, 'cron', minute=0)
```

This should make the job fire every hour at the 00 mark. [More information about using cron style jobs with the APScheduler library can be found here](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/triggers/cron.html)

Comment: This must work.. but as soon as I changed this to 'cron', application was completely blocked.. I changed it to background scheduler, and now it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You could start the program and then pause it until the time is what you want, like this:

```
chosen_time = 9:00 #change to whatever your starting time is   
if datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")) != chosen_time:
    sched.pause()
else:
    sched.resume()
```